# Conditional Probability and Independence

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be events, and $A,C$ be pairwise independent. Can I say that $$P(A\mid B \cap C)=P(A\mid B)$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The notation $B,C$ would be used for random variables $X,Y$. But for sets you should use $B\cap C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's only true if $A,C$ are conditionally independent given $B$.

Counter-example: toss a fair die with events:

$$B=\{2,4,6\},\quad A=\{2,4\},\quad C=\{1,2,3\}.$$

Then, $P(A\cap C)=P(\{2\}) = 1/6 = P(A)P(C),\;$ so that $A,C$ are independent.

However,

$$P(A\mid B,C)=P(\{2,4\}\mid \{2\})=1 \\
  P(A\mid B)=P(\{2,4\}\mid \{2,4,6\})=2/3.$$

Comment: If A depended on B, and $P(C|B\cap A)=P(C|B)$, then would it be true?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yes, it is true even if we only have $P(C|B,A)=P(C|B)$, because this condition _also_ says that $A,C$ are conditionally independent given $B$. To see this: $$P(C|B,A)=P(C|B)\implies P(A,B,C)/P(A,B)=P(B,C)/P(B) \\ \implies P(A,B,C)/P(B,C)=P(A,B)/P(B)\\ \implies P(A|B,C)=P(A|B).$$

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample. Let $Ω=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ with $P(a_i)=1/4$ (equally likely). Let $$A=\{a_1,a_2\},\quad B=\{a_2,a_3\},\quad C=\{a_1,a_3\}$$ The sets $A,B,C$ are pairwise but not mutually independence. In this case $$P(A\mid B\cap C)=0 \quad \text{while} \quad P(A\mid B)=\frac12$$

Comment: If A depended on B, and $P(C|B\cap A)=P(C|B)$, then would it be true?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "no".

E.g. substitute $B=A\cup C$. If $0<P(A\cup C)<1$ then:

$P(A\mid (A\cup C)\cap C)=P(A\mid C)=P(A)\neq P(A\mid A\cup C)$

---

You are actually asking wether the following statement holds if $P\left(A\cap B\right)=P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)$:

$$P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)P\left(B\right)=P\left(A\cap B\right)P\left(B\cap C\right)$$

and the answer on that is: not in general.

Note that the LHS equals $P\left(A\mid B\cap C\right)P\left(B\cap C\right)P\left(B\right)$
and the RHS equals $P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B\cap C\right)P\left(B\right)$.

Comment: If A depended on B, and $P(C|B\cap A)=P(C|B)$, then would it be true?